# ShellExecute runs 'administrator required' application minimized

Tags: vb.net, shell, minimized

I have a line of code that opens an administrator required application that requires you to click 'OK' to the consent box that pops up.

```
ShellExecute(Me.Handle, "open", "c:\myapp.exe", "", "", 5)
```

However when it runs the application, the consent box is opened minimized. Normally, it shows up directly when you double click on 'MyApp.exe', however through ShellExecute the authentication is minimized. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
ShellExecute(NULL, "open", yourAppName, "", "", SW_SHOWNORMAL )
```

Hope, it will solve your problem.